# "Load more" button using Servlet,JQuery,JSP

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets, web

I am trying to implement simple "load more" button in my project. I have grid with items and I want to load more items when somebody clicks on load more button.I found some tutorials but they are mostly for PHP. The ones I found for servlets added just some text or simple html elements.  I want to add a dynamicly created html elements from jsp. I know I could just write it as string response directly in the servlet but I want to have it as much simple as possibly can be.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario is simple. When the user presses the button make an ajax call to the servlet where you make the query to the database, create a json object and return it to the client. Then construct the required html elements dynamically with javascript in the succes callback function.

Comment: yeap, thats the proper way +1

Comment: But how Can I put a linked list of some objects into Json? I could imagine it with just one object but this requires like 12 of them.

Comment: Take a look at this https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples .

Comment: I made it by generating html with jsp on the server side, then sending it back to javascript an attaching it.